# Conditional ordering by two fields

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
     * 
FROM 
     PENDIENTESCOBRO 
ORDER BY 
     NPENDIENTE ASC
     , DFECHA
```

`NPENDIENTE` can be a negative or positive number. I want that when this field is higher than 0, stops using this order and takes `ORDER BY DFECHA`.

How can I do this?

Comment: How are records with `NPENDIENTE > 0` to be sorted relative to records with `NPENDIENTE <= 0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM PENDIENTESCOBRO
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN NPENDIENTE>0 THEN 1 ELSE NPENDIENTE END ASC,
  DFECHA
```

This is because you can use CASE espressions in SQLite ORDER BY clauses. The CASE I put makes all positive (>0) NPENDIENTE values have the same order value... so rows are then ordered by DFECHA.